# Spring Social Twitter Oauth

Tags: spring, twitter, twitter-oauth, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I want to use spring social to develop an twitter app which will update status and upload photos.I am not able to understand how to do Oauth authentication using Spring social.All examples I saw talks about hardcoding the accesstoken which would work only for that particular user.I dont want to hardcode anything except the app keys.

Kindly some one explain me how to do Twitter Oauth using spring social.I went through the official documentation of spring framework but got confused when I saw the other examples..

Thanks

Comment: I just found this example, which works pretty good.

Answer (score 13):

- *I saw talks about hardcoding the accesstoken which would work only for that particular user.I dont want to hardcode anything except the app keys.*

"app keys" a.k.a. `consumer { key, secret }` pair authorizes your app to use Twitter APIs that do not require *user authentication*. Think about it as you app browsing a twitter website without being logged in. Hence you'd have an ability to search, get timelines, etc.. => read only.

In case you'd like to *post* something back, you'd have to make you app do that *on behalf* of a real Twitter account / user. Think about someone writing a Twitter client => it can be downloaded by many *different* users, hence it needs two things to function properly:

- Be a registered Twitter application => have `consumer { key, secret }` pair
- Be able to post tweets / images *on behalf* of the user => have `access { token, secret }` pair

In order to get that access { token, secret } pair, you'd have to have an "OK" from that user/account.

That is where OAuth comes in => it sends the user to the confirmation page, where he clicks "OK, I allow this app to *post* on my behalf". This "OK" then gets converted to the `OAuthToken` that your app can use.

If all you want is to post updates on behalf of yourself, then you need to approve your own Twitter app, and persist that `OAuthToken` to be used by your app.

Unfortunately Twitter [does not yet support](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/397) OAuth 2.0, hence you'd have to do more... You'd have to do OAuth 1.0a.

Spring Social documentation describes the OAuth 1.0a flow [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html#service-providers-oauth1), where you can see the flow visually.

On order to "code" this flow using Spring Social APIs, you should first request access {token, value} pair ( there is a convenience [ConnectController](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html) for it btw ):

```
TwitterConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
    new TwitterConnectionFactory( "consumerKey", "consumerSecret" );
OAuth1Operations oauthOperations = connectionFactory.getOAuthOperations();
OAuthToken requestToken = oauthOperations.fetchRequestToken( "https://my-callback-url", null );
String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl( requestToken, OAuth1Parameters.NONE );
response.sendRedirect( authorizeUrl );
```

And once it comes back (to your callback URL) you can use `OAuth1Operations` to get [OAuthToken](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/oauth1/OAuthToken.html) which is exactly that pair.

```
// upon receiving the callback from the provider:
OAuthToken accessToken = oauthOperations.exchangeForAccessToken(
    new AuthorizedRequestToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier), null);
```

Now, as you have all you need, you have choices:

#### Create a TwitterTemplate from that `OAuthToken`:

```
String consumerKey = "..."; // The application's consumer key
String consumerSecret = "..."; // The application's consumer secret
String accessToken = accessToken.getValue();
String accessTokenSecret = accessToken.getSecret();
Twitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate( consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret );
```

#### Create a Twitter Connection object

```
Connection<Twitter> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection( accessToken );
```

Once you get the `Connection`, you might want to persist it via `ConnectionRepository` as [shown here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html#service-providers-persisting-connections), so you don't have to go through obtaining access token again.

Here is [Connection API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/connect/Connection.html).

Comment: This spring social sample application - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/tree/master/spring-social-showcase-sec will ask the user to sign in and will allow him to post tweets from your application into his time line.

Comment: Thank You so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is good, but is only part of the story...

There are at least 3 levels at which you may work with Spring Social: (1) Using the TwitterTemplate directly, in which case you'd need to obtain the access token and secret through some means of your own, (2) use OAuth1Template, perhaps through TwitterConnectionFactory as the previous answer showed, to get the access token and from that create the TwitterTemplate, in which case you'd have to handle the redirects and callbacks yourself or (3) use Spring Social's ConnectController to handle everything for you.

Using ConnectController involves the least amount of OAuth work on your part. You just configure the appropriate pieces in Spring and ConnectController takes care of the rest. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html for details.

I encourage you to have a look at the Spring Social Showcase sample at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples. It uses ConnectController to handle by Twitter and Facebook connections. And, of course, you're welcome to ask questions on the Spring Social forum at http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?82-Social.

Comment: [ConnectController](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/connecting.html) is actually mentioned in the previous answer with exactly same link. Tell you the truth, documentation of the access { token, secret } pair is very confusing for all 3 ways, hence I gave an example of how exactly it happens [by the way mentioning all the same 3 approaches :)].